# Why connect accept a third parameter,how to pass it in

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I read the [source code](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/index.js) of connectJS,this part confuse me

```
function createServer() {
  function app(req, res, next){ app.handle(req, res, next); }
  merge(app, proto);
  merge(app, EventEmitter.prototype);
  app.route = '/';
  app.stack = [];
  return app;
}
module.exports = createServer;
```

Basically `next` is a final handler when the internal stack is exhausted and
`app` should go directly to for `http.createServer` which accept a function of length 2 .However the `app` declared to accept 3 parameters.So where to pass in the third parameter ?

For anyone read the source code ,the point should be clear.If never read the source code,I highly recommend to read it,it is short.And then,can go back to this question

Comment: Cool, cool... did you also read [their documentation](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) instead of the source code? Because it explains this basic behaviour, since it's the underpinning of how middleware works in Sencha's connect (and derivative projects like Express.js)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  Sure I did ,please show me a way could pass in the `next` parameter , The `app` is already returned before the client could do anything !!!!

Comment: @Guigui: Downvotes are anonymous. I am not an expert on node.js but you definitely seem to have a very belligerent attitude toward people who are here to help you on their own time with no obligation. In point of fact, your question isn't very clear: what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: I use Express.js on a daily basis and have a fair number of packages on npmjs.com, so: yes, I *might* know something about this. And what I know is that the connect documentation explains (quite well, in fact, it's well written) how to use it. Just read it, assimilate what it tells you, and done. No need to ask Stackoverflow this, you have the power to answer this question on your own.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I use express for more than a year before I start to read the source code ! please read it yourself and you will know what I am talking

Comment: If you believe I am answering the wrong question (and I could be, of course), please update your post to be more explicit in what you need answered. Right now your question appears to be "how do I pass in `next`?", which is basic Connect/Express behaviour and well-documented. In terms of source code you show, the behaviour seems pretty obvious: a function `app` is defined as having thee arguments, and falls through to `handle` that is tacked onto `app` right after it gets defined. Then `EventEmitter.prototype` gets slapped on for good measure.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans connect source code is not long ,200 lines including the docs ,every part is clear for me ,except this one. It is not the `next` as a function parameter .It `next` in the is a final handler which has a default value.From external view ,no way to override the default one,that is why I ask the question

Comment: then please update your question to explain that this is how you understand the source code to work in your question (not in the comments, I'm not the only one looking at it, and certainly not the only one you want to have potentially answering it), and why you think that based on what other code, and that despite your expected trace, that is not what's happening. You'll likely get better answers from more people that way. I need to step out, but good luck. And as advice: good idea to delete inflammatory comments. They don't help get an answer, but *do* help get questions put on hold.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ,I update the question to make it more clear.Recommend spend an afternoon to read the code,you will be benefited from it

Answer (score 0):

To those who concerns,I find the answer to this question
We can do something like this

```
var connect=require('connect')();

var http=require('http')

http.createServer(function (req,res) {
    connect(req,res,function() {
        console.log("I am next")
    })
})
```

In this way,we can pass in the `next` as the final handler

Normally we use

```
var connect=require('connect')();

var http=require('http')

http.createServer(connect)
```

Just overlook the hidden feature of connect framework

Also,this feature do not put into [their document](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) for some reason

=========================== update =================================

After read some test case in connect ,got the better understanding why it exist

```
 it('should work as middleware', function(done){
    // custom server handler array
    var handlers = [connect(), function(req, res, next){
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end('Ok');
    }];

    // execute callbacks in sequence
    var n = 0;
    function run(req, res){
      if (handlers[n]) {
        handlers[n++](req, res, function(){
          run(req, res);
        });
      }
    }

    // create a non-connect server
    var server = http.createServer(run);

    request(server)
    .get('/')
    .expect(200, 'Ok', done);
  });
```

Just like `next` can work as a signal to move forward in the stack inside connect,The `next` in a framework level can chain connect to another framework,although,there is no obvious way to chain middleware together in connect.Maybe express can take advantage this hidden feature more

Comment: If not in doc then it might change without notice and we must not use it.

Comment: @NidhinDavid thanks,at least it is the correct answer to this question rather than down voting the question directly without even understanding the topic

Comment: I didn't down vote your question, neither anybody for a long time

Comment: @NidhinDavid sorry for that,I am kind of out of mind :)